# Set dll PATH to launch program in nmake makefile

Tags: windows, nmake

I'm writing a nmake makefile that has a target for the test suite execution.

Unfortunately, the test suite needs a DLL that is not located in the PATH environment variable.

In the makefile I need something like this (that obviously doesn't work :-)

```
# run the test
test:
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%BOOST%\stage\lib\
    test_suite.exe
```

How can I specify the PATH inside my windows makefile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and I'm going to answer my question.

In nmake makefile you cannot set variables inside target rules.

The solution to my problem is:

```
# variables:
PATH=$(PATH);$(BOOST)\stage\lib\

...

# run the test
test:
    test_suite.exe
```